# Counting number of pixels each row in an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, line

For a project, I am required to find the point distance between lines in an image. The method that I have thought of was to convert the image into a binary image and count the number of white pixels against a black background in each row. I have attached my code and it works well provided that the line is perfectly straight.

By the way this is a sample image that will be analysed. I plan to turn into binary/ run a line detection algorithm to find the boundaries of the two green strips in the wire as the distance between them is of concern.

[image: (http://i.imgur.com/Q5Ef0eJ.jpg)]
[image]

```
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtnkS.png'); %// Read image
imBinary = double(im2bw(im)); %// Just in case - Convert to binary, 
                              %// then make double for sum
histogram = sum(imBinary,2); %// Compute row-wise histograms
stem(1:size(imBinary,1), histogram); %// Plot this histogram
xlabel('Row number');
ylabel('White pixel count');
grid;
diffs = diff([0; histogram]);
threshold = 100; %// Define threshold here 
rows = find(diffs >= threshold);
```

This code returns a histogram and the distance between peaks indicates the spacing between the lines.

To rectify the issue of bent lines, I am thinking of using a method that analyses columns of an image (say 100 pixels), then it loops until it cycles through the entire image (0-100 column, then 101-200 until the width of the image).

I have my pseudocode here:

```
for (loop through rows) 
    for (loop for coloumns) 
        count pixels at p(row, col) 
    end loop for columns 
    column counter = column counter - 1
    if column counter <= 0 then save the number of pixels counter and set column counter = 10
end row loop
```

However, being a ChemE major, coding is not my strong point and I struggle very much with loops.

I just want to be able to incorporate the aforementioned code inside this loop so it can break a bent line into a many psuedo-straight lines to be able to compute an "average" or a series of discrete line spacings.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hm :) I knew I recognized that image and that image from somewhere!  I'll have a look at your logic now, and I'll suggest something if I think this will work.

Comment: +1 for runnable code! Rarity on `Stackoverflow`.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks! you are really awesome and I really appreciate your help, unfortunately coding isn't one of my strengths and its easy to say what i wanna do but writing the code and syntax is a whole different ball game to me :/

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is a `point distance`? Is it the perpendicular distance? What would be the "answer(s)" for your given image?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, in the case of the first image it would be the perpendicular distance between wire (ie. the number of black pixels in a column that separates the white pixels). 

In a pseudo- straight segment of a picture it would be the same (number of black pixels in a column)

Comment: I still don't get it :-) How many answers are there for this image? Do you need the distances between all pairs of lines? How do you calculate the distance between the non-parallel lines in the 3rd row? Can you maybe mark in red the lengths you are trying to calculate?

Comment: @MarkSetchell the non parallel lines are merely "noise", since the code counts number of white pixels along a row and the histogram function returns a graph with the number of white pixels and the "threshold" function sets the minimum height of the peaks for it to be a line.

in this case, from top to bottom, each parallel line has 148, 217 and 478 number of white pixels respectively and using the "diff" function calculates the distance between these parallel lines (number of blacks between each line). In this case it is 69 (1st and 2nd)  and 258 (2nd and 3rd) pixels.

Comment: What happens if your input image is rotated - surely your code will only work if the lines are perfectly horizontal? Don't you have to allow for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60610/discussion-between-user3788581-and-mark-setchell).

Comment: @rayryeng do you have any suggestions haha :) Matlab image analysis saviour :p

Comment: @user3788581 - hahaha you're funny. I knew I recognized that code from somewhere... especially the comments. I forgot I wrote that.  I'll see what I can do.  I haven't looked at this lately as I've been busy.

Comment: @user3788581 - What exactly did you want to do with the bent lines? Ignore them? I'm not quite sure what you want to do here.

Comment: @rayryeng Yep, the bent lines can just be ignored. For clarification in the photo I attached of the actual image the lines aren't perfectly straight (bent) so I thought by cutting the image up into many pseudo straight images it would be able to use your code much more better.

Comment: @rayryeng any suggestions? :p I am just trialling some of the ideas the other users have suggested but don't really fit the criteria of a bendy line...

Answer (score 0):

I have never run Matlab in my life, so I cannot tell you the exact lines of code in Matlab... however I can tell you how to remove non-horizontal lines in general terms.

You simply convolve the image with an appropriate kernel that is horizontally oriented, so for your needs the kernel would be:

```
0       0       0
0.33    0.33    0.33
0       0       0
```

So basically each pixel in the output image becomes the average of itself and its left and right neighbours.

**Start Image**

[image]

ImageMagick command:

```
convert lines.png -convolve "0,0,0,0.33,0.33,0.33,0,0,0" -threshold 99.99% horiz.jpg
```

**End Image**

[image]

By the way, your lines are actually 5 pixels thick, so you may need to run a bigger kernel to remove them, say 9x9 where all the coefficients are zero except the middle (5th) line where they are all 1/9 (i.e. 0.111).

I worked that out using ImageMagick to resize your image to a vertical column a single pixel wide with this command:

```
convert lines.png -resize 1x844! -threshold 50% txt:
```

which gives the following output showing your white lines are at offsets 149,218,476 lines from the top.

```
...
0,144: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,145: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,146: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,147: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,148: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,149: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white    <- Centre of your line
0,150: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,151: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,152: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,153: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,154: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
...
0,213: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,214: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,215: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,216: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,217: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,218: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white    <- Centre of your line
0,219: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,220: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,221: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,222: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,223: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
...
0,471: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,472: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,473: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,474: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,475: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,476: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white    <- Centre of your line
0,477: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,478: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
0,479: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,480: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,481: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
...
```

Here is the "squidged" image - on a red background so you can see it:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting alternative! I have not used ImageMagick before and can see how this solution works but I would like to put it into a loop where I can analyse slightly bendy lines (which is my primary problem). I have updated the question with a picture of the image to be analysed.

Answer (score 0):

convolve your histogram:

```
h_accu = conv(histogram,(1:10)/10);
figure;plot(h_accu)
```

here `10` served as window size, it should be adjust according to the straightness of your line.

btw, a more general way to find the lines is [hough transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, could you please elaborate on how the hough transform applies to this problem? I have read some literature on it and it seems to detect the lines visually but does not actually give quantitative feedback on the distance (unless I am missing something)

Comment: The output of hough transform would be pairs of 'theta' and 'd', each of them represents a detected line. Theta is the orientation of the line, and d is the distance to the origin of the image. Those values could be used for your computation.